# SQL query return data where author is selected from array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, where-clause

How can I return posts from two or more different authors using one single SQL query? Authors array is received from the database and is different for every single user (it depend on what author you are following).

I return `$array` variable with IDs of the authors.

```
$array = array(15, 12, 18); //this array is returned from database and is always different
$posts = DB::table('posts') -> where('author', $array]) -> orderBy('date', 'DESC') -> get();

foreach($posts as $post) {
  echo "Posted by " . $post->author;
}
```

How can I return all posts, posted by authors 15, 12, 18 using a single line or just returning to single-sql query and sort it by date?

I've tried to make different sql selects for every single creator and merge arrays, but then it's very hard to order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`whereIn`](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#where-clauses), which is specifically built for your purpose:

```
$posts = DB::table('posts') 
    -> whereIn('author', $array) 
    -> orderBy('date', 'DESC') 
    -> get();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need use `whereIn` instead of `where`:

```
->whereIn('author', $array)
```

Now your query looks like below:

```
$posts = DB::table('posts')->whereIn('author', $array)-> orderBy('date', 'DESC')->get();
```